# How to persist some values in outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook, persist

As part of what I am doing I need to access variables even after the session with the Outlook is closed. Is there any way to persist value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of outlook plugins, but I think you can persist values in whatever ways you prefer: to database, text files, binary files etc.
Or do you have strict security restriction to do so?

Comment: thanks for u r answer i am using a text file to persisit my data

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is to use something like cookies, see this for more info:

- [Excel VBA, XMTHTTP & Cookies : XML SOAP](http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/86831-excel-vba-xmthttp-cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Open one of the default folder you know will always exist (e.g. Inbox) using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, then use `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623414.aspx for an example.